# Access text file in mac bundle

Tags: java

I've bundled a simple app that reads some static data in from text files and provides the user an interface to search the data. Currently to read the files I just do the classic `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));`, but I get file not found exceptions running the application.

I can run the created .jar file fine because I copied the txt files to the same directory level. Running the executable however fails even if I try the same thing.

Directory Structure:
Contents [ Java [.jar, libs], MacOS [unix-executable], plugins [jdk], Resources [.icns ] ]

Comment: where your data.txt does resides? is it in current folder?

Comment: you `data.txt` should be in root folder. Or try with this './data.txt'(make sure your file is in root folder)

Comment: so the executable is in contents/macos, and the files are in the same folder. ill give the ./ a go

Comment: ./ doesnt work. ill edit the q with directory structure

Comment: If you can't make sure where you should put the txt file, use the full path of the file. like "~/xxx/xxx/data.txt". as to how to check the full path, click the file and presss command+i.

Comment: that works, but is there a more elegant solution? one that would work when just running the eclipse project and when deploying?